# Paragraph based textarea format in laravel blade?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a textarea input from a user like that:

```
This is first paragraph.
This is second paragraph. The paragraph continues. The end of it.
Third paragraph.
```

I want to render it like that in laravel blade:

```
<p>This is first paragraph.</p>
<p>This is second paragraph. The paragraph continues. The end of it.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
```

Please note that, I don't want to use breaklines. Beside these, I want to escape each paragraph like that:

```
<p>e(This is first paragraph.)</p>
<p>e(This is second paragraph. The paragraph continues. The end of it.)</p>
<p>e(Third paragraph.)</p>
```

How can I perform that?

Comment: You can `perform` that using a `WYSIWYG` editor

Comment: But I don't want user input with html tags, and I escape them, just like this Stackoverflow comment texarea does. -> <p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just explode the string by the end of line character and then loop through it.

```
<?php $paragraphs = explode(PHP_EOL, $string); ?>

@foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph)
    <p>{{{ $paragraph }}}</p>
@endforeach
```

`{{{` `}}}` escape your string like `e()` would.

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution I seek. But $paragraphs is composed of one array element which is the paragraph itself. How can I iterate through the real paragraphs?

Comment: That means the newline character is not the same as your PHP_EOL constant. Maybe try  out "\n", "\r" and "\r\n" instead of PHP_EOL